# How to convert getInitialPropsTo getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this function in my next js app , in _app.js file.
I want to convert it in getServerSidePops function but I get errors whatever I try.

```js
App.getInitialProps = async (props) => {
  const { Component, ctx, router } = props

  let apiClient = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? getApiClient() : null

  let cmsProps = {}

  // In case `getInitialProps` here fails, Next.js will call this method again
  // with `./_error.js` as `Component` and the stack trace as context.
  if (Component.displayName === Error.displayName) {
    const pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)

    return {
      cmsProps: {},
      pageProps: {
        ...pageProps,
        page: {
          ...pageProps.page,
          disableAppBase: true,
        },
      },
      status: pageProps.statusCode,
    }
  }

  const pageProps = {}

  try {
    if (ctx.req) {
      const cookies = new Cookies(ctx.req, ctx.res, {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      })

      apiClient = new ApiClient(cookies)
      cmsProps = await fetchGlobalSettings(ctx)
    }

    let url

    apiClient.readCookies()

    const domain =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? publicRuntimeConfig.TINYLINK_PREFIX
        : 'http://localhost:3000'

    const market = router.locale !== `redirect` && router.locale
    const marketAsPath = market ? `/${router.locale}` : ``
    const selectedMarket = apiClient.selectedMarket
    const selectedMarketAsPath = selectedMarket ? `/${selectedMarket}` : ``
    const origUrl = `${domain}${marketAsPath}${ctx.asPath.split('?')[0]}`.replace(/\/$/, '')

    const routingOpts = {
      url: `${domain}${marketAsPath}${ctx.asPath.split('?')[0]}`.replace(/\/$/, ''),
      urlLanguage: false,
      routing: true,
    }

    if (ctx.req) {
      routingOpts.ipAddress = ctx.req?.headers?.['x-real-ip'] || ''
    }

    const appInit = async (opts) => {
      const init = await apiClient.init(opts)

      if (init.url) {
        url = init.url
      }
    }

    if (!apiClient.sessionToken) {
      await appInit(routingOpts)
    } else {
      try {
        let decoded

        if (router.locale === 'redirect' && selectedMarket) {
          decoded = await apiClient.decodeShortLink({
            ...routingOpts,
            routing: false,
            url: `${domain}${selectedMarketAsPath}${ctx.asPath.split('?')[0]}`.replace(/\/$/, ''),
          })
        } else {
          decoded = await apiClient.decodeShortLink(routingOpts)
        }

        url = decoded.url
      } catch (error) {
        // If token error reinitialise app
        await appInit(routingOpts)
      }
    }

    if (apiClient?.cookies) {
      apiClient?.cookies.set('MARKET', router.locale === 'redirect' ? 'eu' : router.locale, {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        domain: publicRuntimeConfig.COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        sameSite: publicRuntimeConfig.COOKIE_SAMESITE,
      })
    }

    if (url && url !== origUrl) {
      if (ctx.asPath.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
        url = `${url}?${ctx.asPath?.split('?', 2)[1]}`
      }

      if (ctx.res) {
        // On the server, we'll use an HTTP response to
        // redirect with the status code of our choice.
        // 307 is for temporary redirects.
        ctx.res.writeHead(307, { Location: url })
        ctx.res.end()
      } else {
        // On the client, we'll use the Router-object
        // from the 'next/router' module.
        router.replace(url)
      }
      // Return an empty object,
      // otherwise Next.js will throw an error
      return { redirect: true }
    }

    cmsProps.hello = await apiClient.hello()
    cmsProps.products = formatProducts(cmsProps?.hello?.products)
    cmsProps.translations = formatTranslations(cmsProps?.hello?.translations)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error)
  }

  return {
    cmsProps,
    pageProps,
  }
}
```

Convert this function to getServerSideProps function.

Comment: Please do not add repeated text to your post to get around the quality filter message: “It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details”. Instead, improve your question by including _meaningful_ information about the issue or issues facing your implementation. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Currently, you simply cannot use `getServerSidePops` in the custom `_app`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats.